# Resolve dependency on token validation and on controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to share a security object through an application using dependency injection:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IRequesterFilter, RequesterFilter>();
```

The object is populated when a token is validated:

```cs
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.Authority = "https://xxxxxx.xxx";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = "https://yyyyyy.yyyy";
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnValidatedToken = context =>
        {
            var requestFilter = context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService<IRequesterFilter>();
            requestFilter.RequesterLevel = RequesterLevelEnum.Client;
            requestFilter.AppId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Principal.FindFirst("appid").Value;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});
```

But when I get IRequesterFilter from the controller constructor, the object is not initialized:

```cs
public ValuesController(IRequesterFilter requestFilter)
{
    var x = requestFilter;
}
```

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1.

Comment: I've managed to accomplish the same in a different way, populating the data of `RequesterFilter`, through `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User` and deleting the code at `OnValidatedToken`.
But I'm still curious why it didn't work the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong container.

You are using `context.HttpContext.ApplicationServices.GetService<IRequesterFilter>()`, which is for application managed/application-wide objects, usually singletons.

For scoped services you have to use the scoped container (called `RequestServices`), which is would be `context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IRequesterFilter>()`.

Please note that `ApplicationServices` will be removed **from HttpContext** with ASP.NET Core RC2, which will be a breaking change in the way are using it right now.

Comment: After searching my code for `ApplicationServices` in order to not use it, I haven't found a way of substitute it by other container in this case:

`public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
 using (var dbContext = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<MainDbContext>())
 {
  dbContext.Database.Migrate();
 }
}`

Any suggestions?

Comment: In Configure/Startup.cs you can't use `RequestServices` as the name suggest it's per request and during the startup there is no request. Should have been more clear, everything that is called or resolved during a request should be done via `RequestServices`. Application wide services, i.e. Cache service etc. still gets resolved via application wide container. In RC the `ApplicationServices` isn't part of `HttpContext` anymore, so you won't be able to use it in i.e. an filter. `IApplicationBuilder` still h as `ApplicationServices` but is only available in Startup.cs